# How do I create a float64 vector from a DataFrame where for each entry of the DF column there are n vector entry?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I have a DataFrame where there is a column `(70x1)` representing aggregate yearly payments (yp) (float64 type) to be made by a certain corp. How can I create a numerical vector with monthly payment `(840x1)` where **each** monthly payment is given by

`(yp/12)*np.random.normal(yp,1)`

I tried with `np.repeat()` to recreate 12 monthly payment equal to the yearly one but then I got problems when it comes to add the random part.

Comment: If you use **12** random values for the monthly payment, it is unlikely for their sum to be equal to the yearly payment...

Comment: Yes I do not need them to be exactly equal. I just need them to be normal with the mean equal to the yearly payment and some noise around it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the standard deviation for each year to be constant (say 1.0), you can just ask np.random to provide everything:

```
mp = np.random.normal(yp/12, 1, (12,70))
```

will give you a 2D array 12x70.

You can even have the standard deviation depend on the yearly payment by building an array of same size as the yearly payment:

```
std = yp / 1000
mp = np.random.normal(yp/12, std, (12,70))
```

(use np.random.seed if you want reproducible results...)